# difficulty in phone setup with android studio

Tags: react-native

Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
build-tools;30.0.2 Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2
To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

Using Android SDK: /Users/harshit/Library/Android/sdk

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Android Studio? if so try to install it from the Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK > Install Licensing Library and any other libraries that you are missing.